# Multiple consoles or display screens in Java?

Tags: java

I am using eclipse to run my java code. There are two methods which produce some output. I don't want their outputs displayed in succession on the same console/window. Is it possible to direct the output of each method to its own window/console ?

Comment: In case you don't get the solution for this, direct output of each of these methods to a separate file.

Comment: @Sudhanshu - how do i do that ?

Comment: You can use System.out and System.err then you can redirect them (or at least colour them differently). If things get more complex then that, look at a logging library.

Comment: One option is to use two loggers. Else use basic file writers to write to separate files in these methods.

Comment: @Thilo - Please tell me what you mean by 'things get more complex' > I don't even know what simple is, let alone complex. So I need some information about those things.

Comment: Complex means "creating output that does not just go to the console, is nicely formatted and annotated, and can be configured without changing the program". Probably what you want here. Try to find an introduction to Logging (which unfortunately in Java can get quite complex).

Comment: A near-trivial task by using a GUI, try [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html).

Comment: @Dukeling - makes sense. But I will have to learn swing for that. Is there any API which does all this for me. I don't want to code swing UI for this task.

Comment: @Time Not sure about Eclipse, but with NetBeans getting a Swing GUI going is as easy as a few drag+drop's. Appending output to the text areas would probably be one or two lines of code.